# How to handle non-callable object type of error

Tags: python-2.7, vtk

I am trying to do an animation using python with VTK in TKinter, meanwhile I got stuck with following error and I don't understand this error, please note this error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't understand which object is null or none!. For identifying this I put print statements along with function arguments
but I couldn't find out!. Kindly note my following code and someone please help me out quickly. The whole program I am just doing
to add a VTK sphere object in a rendering screen and I want to animate by moving this sphere in a timer count event.

The error hitting line is

```
obj_renwin.actor.SetPosition(cone_Obj.timer_count, cone_Obj.timer_count,5);
```

Please note the detailed code

```
import vtk

class Cone():

    def __init__ (cone_Obj):             
        cone_Obj.timer_count = 0

    def sphere_render(cone_Obj,obj_renwin):

        obj_renwin.sphereSource = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
        obj_renwin.sphereSource.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        obj_renwin.sphereSource.SetRadius(.5)    
        obj_renwin.actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        obj_renwin.mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        obj_renwin.mapper.SetInputConnection(obj_renwin.sphereSource.GetOutputPort())
        obj_renwin.actor.SetMapper(obj_renwin.mapper)
        obj_renwin.actor.SetPosition(-0.5,.5,-0.5)
        obj_renwin.prop = obj_renwin.actor.GetProperty()
        obj_renwin.add_actors(obj_renwin.actor)
        obj_renwin.renwin.Render()

        return obj_renwin.actor     

    def animation(cone_Obj,obj_renwin):              
        renderwininstance=obj_renwin
        #print renderwininstance        
        renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
        renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(obj_renwin.renwin)
        obj_renwin.renwin.Render()
        renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()      
        renderWindowInteractor.AddObserver('TimerEvent',cone_Obj.execute(cone_Obj,obj_renwin))           
        timerId = renderWindowInteractor.CreateRepeatingTimer(5);
        renderWindowInteractor.Start()

    def execute(self,cone_Obj,obj_renwin):
        print "obj_renwin is..."
        print obj_renwin
        obj_renwin.actor.SetPosition(cone_Obj.timer_count, cone_Obj.timer_count,5);
        cone_Obj.timer_count += 1
        obj_renwin.Render() 


cone_Obj = Cone()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are adding the observer with AddObserver() is incorrect. AddObserver() takes a free function (not a bound one) so you need to define a global function and use that. Here is to reproduce the issue:

```
class Foo():
def execute(self, foo, bar):
    print 'In execute'

foo = Foo()
o = vtk.vtkDataObject()
o.AddObserver('ModifiedEvent', foo.execute(foo, None))
o.Modified()
```

The way VTK implements observers makes it difficult to pass arguments to them. I normally use closure to get around this. Here is an example

```
class Foo():
    def execute(self, foo, bar):
        print 'In execute'

foo = Foo()

def MakeObserver(arg):
    myarg = arg
    def observer(obj, event):
        myarg.execute(None, None)
    return observer

o = vtk.vtkDataObject()
o.AddObserver('ModifiedEvent', MakeObserver(foo))
o.Modified()
```

Comment: It was the correct answer, appreciate you for helping me but how to stop this animation timer? could you please help me

Comment: I have not used timers before but from the documentation, it looks like you need DestroyTimer().

Answer (score 0):

Is you method `sphere_render(cone_Obj,obj_renwin)` called once ? I didn't see any call to this method and you set the actor in it : `obj_renwin.actor = vtk.vtkActor()`

If this method is never called, in  your `execute` method `obj_renwin.actor` is not set.

```
def execute(self,cone_Obj,obj_renwin):
    print "obj_renwin is..."
    print obj_renwin
    obj_renwin.actor.SetPosition(cone_Obj.timer_count,
                                 cone_Obj.timer_count,5);
    [...]
```

Comment: @Maracassian, appriciate you for helping me! I have set the vtk actor with vtk sphere object using mapper, please see the below code line
which shows the vtk sphere is set to the actor via mapper.         obj_renwin.mapper.SetInputConnection(obj_renwin.sphereSource.GetOutputPort())
        obj_renwin.actor.SetMapper(obj_renwin.mapper)
        obj_renwin.actor.SetPosition(-0.5,.5,-0.5)

Comment: @Berk Geveci, I am wondering how to make my function 'execute' as a global function! I thought if I give 'self' argument
in function, it will automatically become global function OR is it just matter of indenting the function from other functions?
Please see my code again below


    def execute(self,cone_Obj,obj_renwin):
        print "obj_renwin is..."


If I understood anything wrongly, kindly correct me

Really appreciate you for responding

Waiting for your reply

Comment: Write this comment on the @Berk Geveci answer's comment space. He will be notified of you question